# pattern matching in controller to route requests

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-web-api2, c#-7.0

Suppose I have a controller:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [Route("Order")]
    public List<MyResponse> Post([FromBody] Order request)
    {
        //validation
        return stuff;
    }
}
```

I need to add some logic:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [Route("Order")]
    public List<MyResponse> Post([FromBody] Order request)
    {
        if (request.noOfWidgets==1) return Cat();
        if (request.noOfWidgets==0) return Dog();
    }
}
```

instead of using `if` statements, we can use pattern matching:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [Route("Order")]
    public List<MyResponse> Post([FromBody] Order request)
    {
        switch(request.noOfWidgets)
        {
            case(1): return Cat();
            case(0): return Dog();

        }
        return new List<MyResponse>();
    }
}
```

suppose our Order object is a disgusting mess:

```
public class Order
{
        public int noOfWidgets {get;set;}
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
        public bool? DisperseCharges { get; set; }
        public bool? IsAdjustable { get; set; }
        public bool? IsPackageChild { get; set; }
        public byte ChargeTypeID { get; set; }
        public byte PriceClass { get; set; }
        public DateTime BeginDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ChargeBeginDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ChargeEndDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime PeriodBeginDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime PeriodEndDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime QuoteDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? PurchaseDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? StepBeginDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? StepEndDate { get; set; }
        public decimal? AgentCost { get; set; }
        public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
        public decimal? BeginRecurs { get; set; }
        public decimal? BilledAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal? BookedCost { get; set; }
        public decimal? ChargeBeginRecurs { get; set; }
        public decimal? ChargeEndRecurs { get; set; }
        public decimal? ChargeQuantity { get; set; }
        public decimal? ChargeRecurs { get; set; }
        public decimal? DisperseAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal? EndRecurs { get; set; }
        public decimal? ETLCost { get; set; }
        public decimal? Factor { get; set; }
        public decimal? Multiplier { get; set; }
        public decimal? NonPayCharge { get; set; }
        public decimal? NonPayRate { get; set; }
        public decimal? NumberOfPeriodsBilled { get; set; }
        public decimal? OtherCost { get; set; }
        public decimal? RealCost { get; set; }
        public decimal? ScheduleBeginRecurs { get; set; }
        public decimal? ScheduleEndRecurs { get; set; }
        public decimal? ScheduleTotalRecurs { get; set; }
        public decimal? SPIFFCost { get; set; }
        public decimal? StandardCharge { get; set; }
        public decimal? StandardRate { get; set; }
        public decimal? SuspendCharge { get; set; }
        public decimal? SuspendRate { get; set; }
        public Guid RequestUID { get; set; }
        public int ChargeClassID { get; set; }
        public int CycleScheduleID { get; set; }
        public int ElementClassID { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int ProductComponentID { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public int QuoteID { get; set; }
        public int YYYYMMCCID { get; set; }
        public int? AccountID { get; set; }
        public int? ARItemID { get; set; }
        public int? BillingChargeClassID { get; set; }
        public int? BillingFrequencyMask { get; set; }
        public int? BillingNumber { get; set; }
        public int? ChargeDays { get; set; }
        public int? ChargeIsWaivable { get; set; }
        public int? ComponentClassID { get; set; }
        public int? ComponentID { get; set; }
        public int? CycleID { get; set; }
        public int? DaysConnected { get; set; }
        public int? DaysInPeriod { get; set; }
        public int? DepositTemplateID { get; set; }
        public int? DiscountComponentID { get; set; }
        public int? DiscountProductComponentID { get; set; }
        public int? DisperseWeight { get; set; }
        public int? DivisionID { get; set; }
        public int? ERateID { get; set; }
        public int? ExemptionTypeID { get; set; }
        public int? FractionalIsWaivable { get; set; }
        public int? GLMapID { get; set; }
        public int? GroupQuantity { get; set; }
        public int? InitialCycleScheduleID { get; set; }
        public int? IsCredit { get; set; }
        public int? ItemID { get; set; }
        public int? ItemPriceID { get; set; }
        public int? LocationID { get; set; }
        public int? NumberOfRecurrences { get; set; }
        public int? Occurrence { get; set; }
        public int? ParentItemID { get; set; }
        public int? ParentProductComponentID { get; set; }
        public int? PatronageTypeID { get; set; }
        public int? PCode { get; set; }
        public int? PriceID { get; set; }
        public int? PriceListID { get; set; }
        public int? PricePlanID { get; set; }
        public int? PriceStepID { get; set; }
        public int? PriceStepScheduleID { get; set; }
        public int? PriceStepTierID { get; set; }
        public int? PriceWeight { get; set; }
        public int? ProductID { get; set; }
        public int? ProviderID { get; set; }
        public int? ReceivableID { get; set; }
        public int? ReportAreaID { get; set; }
        public int? RevenueGLID { get; set; }
        public int? RootItemID { get; set; }
        public int? RootProductComponentID { get; set; }
        public int? RunningQuantityEnd { get; set; }
        public int? RunningQuantityStart { get; set; }
        public int? SalesRegionID { get; set; }
        public int? SegmentID { get; set; }
        public int? ServiceID { get; set; }
        public int? StepMaxQuantity { get; set; }
        public int? StepMinQuantity { get; set; }
        public int? TaxAreaID { get; set; }
        public int? TaxChargeTypeID { get; set; }
        public int? TaxCountType { get; set; }
        public int? TotalDisperseWeight { get; set; }
        public string AccountUID { get; set; }
        public string BillingFrequency { get; set; }
        public string BillingMethod { get; set; }
        public string ChargeClass { get; set; }
        public string ChargeDescription { get; set; }
        public string ChargeType { get; set; }
        public string FractionalizationMethod { get; set; }
        public string ItemStatus { get; set; }
        public string PriceScheduleAlignment { get; set; }
        public string PriceScheduleBehavior { get; set; }
        public string PrintMethod { get; set; }
        public string QuoteDescription { get; set; }
        public string ReceivableAccount { get; set; }
        public string RevenueAccount { get; set; }
        public string RoundingMethod { get; set; }
        public string TaxServType { get; set; }
        public string TaxTranType { get; set; }
        public string WaiveFractional { get; set; }
        public string WaiverMethod { get; set; }
}
```

**How can I accept a regular `object` and then pattern match on it, like so:**

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [Route("Order")]
    public object Post([FromBody] object request) //note the change to object type rather than Order type
    {
        switch(object)
        {
            case Order order when order.noOfWidgets == 1: return Cat();
            case Order order when order.noOfWidgets == 0: return Dog();
            case Order order when order.noOfWidgets == 3 && TaxTranType == "something": return Elephant();

        }
        return new List<MyResponse>();
    }
}
```

**Can you pattern match from an api controller an `object` into a concrete object like `Order` and then just determine what *type* to return based on pattern matching?**

Comment: How about to add `Order order = request as Order` (and check for null) before `switch`?

Comment: @AleksAndreev thank you, but what if it's a different object, for example instead of Order, i would want to pass in Bill as the request, then it's completely a different object

Comment: I'm assuming that your `Post` method can't handle _any_ type of object (`int` for example) . So a solution is to define an interface that will provide some contract. Then try cast to that interface and execute your `switch`

Comment: thank you. absolutely correct, however, i dont want to have to depend on an interface, i want to simplify as much as possible, and have all of the complexity within the routing logic inside of the controller, i dont want to have to create a separate interface for this

Comment: does changing 
request Type  to dynamic instead of object
solve your problem?

Comment: that's a great idea, but i'm not sure what the benefit would be

Answer (score 2):

> Can you pattern match from an api controller an `object` into a concrete object like `Order` and then just determine what *type* to return based on pattern matching?

Assuming that `request` is an instance of `Order`, then that is indeed how pattern matching works. [Give something similar a try](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAIAYAEqCMBuAWAChUBmbAJkwGFMBvYzJ7c3ANmwBZscAOACgCU9RszGixTAPIAjAFYBTAMbBMAe0wBeTPgmSAzgHcAlsCUALTPzWC9YhkUlPMSgIb6FmY1FXHMh8wUoLy1tHEwQHgBOfgAiHFjBPGwAdkJHZzE3D0w4NQgZABtPAA8I6P4AEliAM0K1V1U6EoBfROTUNLtnbM8AN1cwTAB9ctwY2KgNAFtGi3bU9MyWvRWiFqA===).

C# 7's pattern matching is fairly limited, but it supports type patterns, which matches, `x is T y` or `switch(x) ... case T y` if `x` is of type `T`.

However, I'm not sure that's what you are wanting to do. If `request` is some arbitary object created from the HTML, then pattern matching won't convert it to an `Order` for you. So if that what you are after, then the answer is "no".